# Are questions about specific hikes on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions about specific hikes on topic? For example asking about trail conditions and difficulty between two points on The Great North Walk.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, though anticipate a longer time frame to get an answer.

Comment: Is there a previous meta discussion to support this answer, or do you just personally feel they should be allowed?